# Why is order of arguments in PHP's hash_equals() function important?

Tags: php, c, security, php-internals, timing-attack

PHP 5.6 introduced [`hash_equals()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php) function for safe comparison of password hashes and prevention of timing attacks. Its signature is:

```php
bool hash_equals(string $known_string, string $user_string)
```

As described in the documentation, `$known_string` and `$user_string` must be of the same length for the function to effectively prevent timing attacks (otherwise, `false` is returned immediately, leaking length of known string).

Further, the docs say:

> **It is important to provide the user-supplied string as the second parameter, rather than the first.**

It seems unintuitive to me that the function is not symmetric in its arguments.

The question is:

- ***Why* is it important that the user string is supplied last?**

---

Here's an excerpt from the function's source code:

```c
PHP_FUNCTION(hash_equals)
{
    /* ... */

    if (Z_STRLEN_P(known_zval) != Z_STRLEN_P(user_zval)) {
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }

    /* ... */

    /* This is security sensitive code. Do not optimize this for speed. */
    for (j = 0; j < Z_STRLEN_P(known_zval); j++) {
        result |= known_str[j] ^ user_str[j];
    }

    RETURN_BOOL(0 == result);
}
```

As for me, the implementation is completely symmetrical regarding the two arguments. 
The only operation which could make any difference is the XOR operator.

- Is it possible that the XOR operator executes in non-constant time, depending on argument values? May its execution time depend on order of arguments (e.g. if the 1st argument is zero)?
- Or is this note from PHP's docs a "reservation" for changes of implementation in future versions?

---

## Edit

As [Morpfh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240985/morpfh) stated, the [initial proposal implementation](https://github.com/realityking/php-src/compare/timing_attack) was different:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(hash_compare)
{
    /* ... */

    /**
     * If known_string has a length of 0 we set the length to 1,
     * this will cause us to compare all bytes of userString with the null byte which fails
     */
    mod_len = MAX(known_len, 1);

    /* This is security sensitive code. Do not optimize this for speed. */
    result = known_len - user_len;
    for (j = 0; j < user_len; j++) {
        result |= known_str[j % mod_len] ^ user_str[j];
    }

    RETURN_BOOL(0 == result);
}
```

As you see, the draft implementation attempted to handle hashes of different lengths, and it processed the arguments asymmetrically. Maybe this draft implementation is not the first one.

**Summarizing:** *the note in the docs about arguments' order seems to be a leftover from draft implementation.*

Comment: I always hate it when documentation tells you something like that and offers no explanation as to why.

Comment: 1) this is a PHP question, so why is it taged with 'c'  2) parameters must be in a certain order because that is the way the function is expecting the parameters.

Comment: @user3629249, 1) it's tagged C because PHP is implemented in C, and it's more about PHP's implementation than usage. 2) sorry, but I can't catch any information in your last statement.

Comment: A contract should be taken at value. Honor it.

Comment: @user2864740: +1, I do! This question wasn't of a practical value, but pure curiosity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Update:

> See comment from Rouven Weßling, (below this answer).

…

---

This is more speculation then an answer, but perhaps you get something out of it.

---

One guess, as you mention, is that it is for probable backward compatibility if the function undergo a future change, for what ever reason, to (1) *not* return false on equal length; thus being vulnerable to leak length information – or (2) other algorithms/checks where one need to know which is which - or (n) ...

---

A likely candidate is that it is a leftover from the proposal to implementation:

- [Request for Comments: Timing attack safe string comparison function](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/timing_attack) Version: 1.0

As such, from *Proposal* one have:

> Users have to be mindful, as it is important that the user supplied string (or a hash of that string) is used as the the second parameter not the first.

This has been present since proposal creation:

- [Request for Comments: Timing attack safe string comparison function](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/timing_attack?rev=1387731779) Version: 0.1

Which can be linked to *References*, for example:

- [Symfony2 constant-time string comparison](https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/edbc3f7a2e23236b01ed18bd4490dd6c7d9eec87/Util/StringUtils.php) (Note: Commit from 2013.)

where one do *not* return on equal length, but loop useLen.

Comment: Probably you're right about it being a leftover from an earlier implementation (or its documentation). I didn't guess to look into history. The proposal implementation (you've provided link to) did compare strings of different lengths bytewise, and it was asymmetric in argument handling.

Comment: RFC and patch author here. You are completely right. My original idea was to try to avoid leaking the length. I left the parameter names to be forward compatible (see http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=139318035405396&w=2)

Also consider this [question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49849/timing-safe-string-comparison-avoiding-length-leak) on security.stackexchange.com which was asked as part of the discussion for the PHP implementation.